# Exchange webmail internal dns

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange, webmail

How do I modify my internal dns-server, so that I can
use the same DNS address as I use externally?

Example; Exchange.domain.com should point to
192.168.X.X instead of external static ip.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Add that entry as an A record in your DNS server.

Assuming this is Windows, go into your DNS manager, and open your forward lookup zones. Add a New Host (A). Put in the servers FQDN as the name and it's LAN IP as the address.

Answer (score 0):

There is already, of course, an exchange host a-record with the internal name "exchange" and points to its static ip 192.168.x.x.

Is it now unproblematic to add a-record exchange.domain.com to point to the same internal ip?
I mean, will any services/outlook clients start to act insane? :D